# German Character Encoding

Tags: character-encoding

I have a big CSV file containing contacts, all the non-latin characters are displayed like that:

ZÃƒÂ¼rich (Zürich)

GrÃƒÂ´ne (Grône)

ChesiÃƒÂ¨res (Chesières)

GenÃƒÂ¨ve (Genève)

I tried to replace them with their right characters, like:

```
str_replace('ÃƒÂ¼', 'ü', $string);
```

They don't change, I tried to insert them in a MySQL database and then replace them, they still be the same.

What should I do?

Comment: This is an encoding problem. Figure out what the original encoding is, then re-encode if necessary, *then* import. Doing patch-work replacement is not going to work.

Comment: Since 'ü' is turning into four bytes instead of two, I think you have three layers of broken encoding going on here. UTF-8 all the way fixes this.

Comment: Of course, any text file _can_ be handled properly but it is a fundamental characteristic of text files, including CSV, that their character encodings must be communicated separately and used correctly. Other common data transfer formats, like JSON, XML, XLSX, … don't have this problem—nor other problems with CSV. (BTW—all of the data you've shown is in [Latin script](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).)

Comment: @tadman I'm coming to realize that some, to my horror, are converting byte arrays to text, not with Base64, but with "Base256"—some single-byte character encoding! Have you seen that? It seems that such a scheme was doubly applied here, as you suggested.

Comment: @TomBlodget Base256? That's what we normally call "binary". You might mean "single byte encoding variant" like Latin1 or Windows-1252.

Answer (score 4):

Please **check the encoding** of the file.
Once you know it, you can read it in the proper way.

After that, you can convert the encoding, e.g., to UTF-8.

Comment: The file that was sent to me seems to be UTF-8 as said by Notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Picking this apart, let's look at the crux of the problem.

- ü in UTF-8: `195, 188`
- ü in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252): `252`
- ü in UTF-8 misinterpreted as Windows-1252: Ã¼ (`195, 188`)

The key thing here is that when seeing UTF-8 (multibyte) to Windows-1252 (single byte) encoding errors a single UTF-8 character often ends up as two nonsense characters. Seeing four here suggests a double mangling:

- ü in UTF-8 misinterpreted as Windows-1252: Ã¼
- Ã¼ in UTF-8 misinterpreted as Windows-1252: ÃƒÂ¼

So there it is. Somehow this was run through two layers of mangling, but to undo it you can force-encode Windows-1252 to UTF-8, then pretend it's Windows-1252 and do it again to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Working from what @tadman described, and from the 132 encodings known to my system, there are several combinations that could have resulted in this mojibake.

```
65001 utf-8 | 1252 iso-8859-1    | 65001 utf-8  | 1252 iso-8859-1 
65001 utf-8 | 1252 iso-8859-1    | 65001 utf-8  | 1254 iso-8859-9 
65001 utf-8 | 1254 iso-8859-9    | 65001 utf-8  | 1252 iso-8859-1 
65001 utf-8 | 1254 iso-8859-9    | 65001 utf-8  | 1254 iso-8859-9 
65001 utf-8 | 28591 iso-8859-1   | 65001 utf-8  | 1252 iso-8859-1 
65001 utf-8 | 28591 iso-8859-1   | 65001 utf-8  | 1254 iso-8859-9 
65001 utf-8 | 28599 iso-8859-9   | 65001 utf-8  | 1252 iso-8859-1 
65001 utf-8 | 28599 iso-8859-9   | 65001 utf-8  | 1254 iso-8859-9 
65001 utf-8 | 65000 utf-7        | 65001 utf-8  | 1252 iso-8859-1 
65001 utf-8 | 65000 utf-7        | 65001 utf-8  | 1254 iso-8859-9
```

So, once you are confident of the exact encodings involved and you check that they are reversible, you can reverse the mojibake like this:

```cs
var latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252, EncoderExceptionFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderExceptionFallback.ExceptionFallback);
var utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001, EncoderExceptionFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderExceptionFallback.ExceptionFallback);
utf8.GetString(latin1.GetBytes(utf8.GetString(latin1.GetBytes("ZÃƒÂ¼rich")))).Dump();
```

C# ([LINQPad](http://share.linqpad.net/jfc7ek.linq))

```cs
Func<Encoding, String> format = (encoding) => $"{encoding.CodePage} {encoding.BodyName}";
var encodings = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(e => e.GetEncoding()).ToList();
(
    from encoding1 in encodings
    from encoding2 in encodings
    from encoding3 in encodings
    from encoding4 in encodings
    where encoding4.GetString(encoding3.GetBytes(encoding2.GetString(encoding1.GetBytes("ü")))) == "ÃƒÂ¼"
    where encoding4.GetString(encoding3.GetBytes(encoding2.GetString(encoding1.GetBytes("ô")))) == "ÃƒÂ´"
    where encoding4.GetString(encoding3.GetBytes(encoding2.GetString(encoding1.GetBytes("è")))) == "ÃƒÂ¨"
    select new { encoding1 = format(encoding1), encoding2 = format(encoding2), encoding3 = format(encoding3), encoding4 = format(encoding4) }
).Dump();
```

Comment: I should have displayed the HeaderName, so 1252 would be "Windows-1252", because Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") is the real ISO 8859-1 (code page 28591).

Comment: The ƒ character isn't present in ISO-8859-1, so it's got to be Windows-1252.